# Backbone: events from external mediator source

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, mediator, custom-events

I'm starting implementing Backbone in a web app.

The app has already some objects of its own, and also a Mediator (here called EventTools) for cross-object event communication. So for ex. an object subscribes like this:

```
  EventTools.add({

    "gt_pos_ready":function(coords){
      //code;
    }.bind(this),

  });
```

And then some other object fires the event:

```
EventTools.fire("gt_pos_ready", args..);
```

Fine. But what if I want a view or other Backbone object to listen to EventTools firing some event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Backbone.Events** instead of your own way to trigger and listen events:

```
_.extend(EventTools, Backbone.Events);

EventTools.on("gt_pos_ready", function(coords) {
  /*Code for gt_pos_ready()*/
});

EventTools.trigger("gt_pos_ready", {LNG:"40.542343",LAT:"32.232423"});
```

I'm sure you are using lodash/underscore because it's a Backbone dep, so this should work.

Comment: That's interesting. So I would not use the original implementation of EventTools (it's a class I made using $.Callbacks functionalities).

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/aYb5B/)

So, then, what should be the nature of EventTools in this case?

Comment: In the end, I realized (as you wrote) that Backbone can act as a Mediator itself. I could simply use Backbone alone. Only for organization purposes, I extended just an empty object an saved to EventTools `var EventTools = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);`

For anyone interested in a simple mediator class that uses $.Callbacks, the link in my previous comment is just good.

Thank you @fcortes